# Add Date Type to prisma2 schema

Tags: date, schema, prisma2

i am trying to add an Date type to my prisma2 schema. I know there is a DateTime type but I am just needing the date.
Because I haven't found anything related to Date I would add an Custom input with day, month and year and create then a Date with the time 12:00 (so I have not so much problems with timezones) or a timestamp.
I hope you have some better ideas or best practices.
best regards and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create custom date scalar type with nexus. if you're using graphql you need to create a custom scalar like [this](https://codeburst.io/custom-scalar-type-in-apollo-graphql-simplified-1a42a4538a25).

```js
const CustomTime = scalarType({
  name: 'CustomTime',
  description: 'Consider time as 12 hour time.',
  asNexusMethod: 'customTime',
  parseValue(value) {
    return moment(value, '').format('')
  }
})
```

Comment: Still didn't get it. I can add the resolver but how I am using it in the schema.prisma file?

Comment: you can't add it in prisma but you can use as input args and then it'll convert it into UTC according to database date and time type.